I'm unable to load asset in flutter
I have been receiving an error messages that (Unable to load asset: "AssetsManifest.bin.jason". The asset doesn't exist or has empty data.)
I have corrected the image path in pubspec.yaml but images are not displaying on my app.

https://pmatatias.medium.com/simple-but-i-didnt-notice-handling-asset-files-in-flutter-484609657b1b try this

To load the asset folder in the Flutter application you have to define the path in pubspec.yaml like this
assets:

{Path to asset folder}
{Path to folder inside asset folder}

for example
If your asset is in project folder, then in pubspec.yaml write it as
assets:

assets/
assets/images

and id your asset folder is in lib folder, then in pubspec.yaml write it as
assets:

lib/assets/
lib/assets/images

After doing this do not forget to run pub get in terminal or when you do changes in pubspec.yaml file it will automatically popup pub get banner.

